# USB TEMPEST attacks: viable range?

Tags: usb, surveillance, sniffing

Is there any published research into the viability of reading Universal Serial Bus signals at a distance from the connection, using electromagnetic radiation [emitted from the bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEMPEST)?

If not, what is the theoretical maximum distance (based on transmit power, frequency, shielding specs, etc) at which such readings would likely be viable with adequate signal-to-noise ratio for the eavesdropper to reconstruct the meanings of the messages being sent over the bus?

Please mention which [version of USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=USB&oldid=717701630#Version_history) your answer applies to (e.g. USB 1.0, USB 1.1, USB 2.0, USB 3.0, USB 3.1, etc).

Use-cases might include:

- Reading data sent to a USB printer in order to be able to view the relevant documents.
- Reading data sent to or from a USB hard disk drive (HDD) in order to be able to view the metadata and/or contents of the relevant files.

Comment: I'm unaware of any papers, and any properly informed replies would likely have to involve a serious amount of research into the practicality of it. It's also going to be hugely variant on the individual implementation - something as trivial as the location and shape of ground and power planes might vastly alter the amount of EMI that's emitted.

Comment: @Polynomial, thanks. One reason for asking here is that it is possible that someone reading this has performed, or knows of, research into the practicality of it. I note your point about the ground and power planes, and I hope that if those do indeed have a substantial effect, then an answerer will explain the properties of the effect.

Comment: I notice someone has down-voted this question without explanation. To them or to anyone thinking of doing the same: please don't do that, it's not constructive. If you think the question is poor as it stands, please first suggest improvements in the comments. Thanks.